# Is WaitForEndOfFrame the same as OnRenderImage?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

In Unity, is `WaitForEndOfFrame`

```c#
void Update() 
{
  StartCoroutine(_c());
}

IEnumerator _c() 
{
  yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
  BuildTexturesForExample();
}
```

identical to `OnRenderImage`?

```c#
void OnRenderImage() 
{
  BuildTexturesForExample();
}
```

(It goes without saying the minimal/useless unity doco on the two calls does not help.)

If not what is done "after" `OnRenderImage` until `WaitForEndOfFrame` is called?

Does anyone have any experience of using the two comparatively?

## Safe to replace??????

Can you ***always safely replace*** a `WaitForEndOfFrame` pattern with `OnRenderImage`?<sup>1</sup>

What's the deal?

---

<sup>1</sup>*(Of course, gizmos/ongui are irrelevant.)*

Comment: Did you check this [Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: Indeed, that's a key link but that doco really doesn't help, @AliKanat ; it's not specific enough.  :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I just found the actual answer in [`OnPostRender`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender.html)

> `OnPostRender` is called after the camera renders all its objects. **If you want to do something after all cameras and GUI is rendered, use `WaitForEndOfFrame` coroutine.**

So (other than I thought and the [ExecutionOrder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) makes it look/sound like) all methods in the Render block (except `OnGUI` and `OnDrawGizmos`) are called on a **per Camera** basis and also note that

> [OnPostRender](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender.html): This function is called only if the script is attached to the camera and is enabled.

or

> [OnRenderImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html): This message is sent to all scripts attached to the camera.

Its purpose is [Post-Processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessingOverview.html) (I only understood how they work looking at the examples.), therefore it actually **takes 2 arguments**!

```c#
OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
```

so you can overwrite the output texture (`dest`) with some render effects after receiving the input (`src`) as in their example

```c#
Material material;

private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{
    // Copy the source Render Texture to the destination,
    // applying the material along the way.
    Graphics.Blit(source, destination, material);
}
```

There is also e.g. [`OnRenderObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderObject.html) which is called on **all** GameObjects (`MonoBehaviour`s) not only the `Camera`. Again until I saw the example I didn't really understand what it does (or what makes it different from `OnRenderImage`). But that example here helped:

```c#
void OnRenderObject()
{
    // Render different meshes for the object depending on whether
    // the main camera or minimap camera is viewing.
    if (Camera.current.name == "MiniMapcam")
    {
        Graphics.DrawMeshNow(miniMapMesh, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
    else
    {
        Graphics.DrawMeshNow(mainMesh, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

*Bonus: I finally understand the real purpose of `Camera.current`! :D*

---

[`WaitForEndOfFrame`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html) on the other hand is called after **all** cameras finished rendering and everywhere not only on a `Camera` GameObject.

> Waits until the end of the frame after **all** cameras **and GUI** is rendered, just before displaying the frame on screen.

---

So I'ld say **No, you can/should not replace `WaitForEndOfFrame` by using `OnRenderImage`!**

Comment: Ahhh!  You completely cracked it.  I had utterly no idea that was the case!  :O

Comment: Boom!@ bounty action  :)